# Did not receive rep for upvote when daily limit not reached

Tags: support

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

My daily rep is 8 (far from 200) and I received 5 upvotes for a comment here: [Converting Float to String Causing Null Pointer Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10646376/converting-float-to-string-causing-null-pointer-exception)

My rep. did not increase, however. Am I missing something?

Comment: Comments do not affect reputation.

Comment: The **You gain reputation when:** list (first link) is exhaustive. If it isn't there, it doesn't generate reputation.

Comment: @tigrang The answer on [How does “Reputation” work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/162704) gives you a full list of ways to gain rep. You can assume that anything that's not in the list doesn't gain you rep.

Comment: [Upvotes and downvotes are different on Meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences). Making jokes can often help you to accumulate upvotes. So can waffles, unicorns, and freehand circles. Not reading the FAQ can help you to accumulate downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only upvotes on questions and answers generate reputation. Upvotes on comments do not.

Answer (score 1):

You don't get rep for comments. Comment votes are just for ordering stuff when the comments collapse--and for users to quickly spot the good stuff in long comment threads.

Comments are third-class citizens here, they aren't content. They're also very prone to being deleted--so no point giving rep for them.